# Wrong url for the images while using same database for two Wordpress installations

Tags: database, options

I have revamped the site hosted at `https://example.com`  and trying to run the new version of the site at `https://example.com/newsite`

**But i want to use the same database with all the links as https://example.com**

Now according to this https://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress

i did the hack in wp-includes/options.php as following

```
if ($option == "siteurl" || $option == "home") {
    // some sample logic to determine if we're on the dev site
    if (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/newsite') == 0
      || strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5), '/newsite/') == 0) {
      return "http://example.com/newsite";
       }
}
```

Everything else is working fine but except for the images.

Path for the images is still

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/c11.png
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/newsite/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/c11.png
```

I am stuck.

Plz help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That little hack just "fixes" the URL when you call the `home` or `siteurl` options, image paths are not affected by that.

Depending on where you want to show images, you could apply a filter to [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), search for your URL and add your subfolder to it. Then you could show images in your post content.

I don´t know if there is a better, "wider" filter to capture all output, but this might get you going...

Comment: like to use preg_replace function.  yup that seems to be the good option as i only want it temporarily.

Comment: Glad I could help you. :-)

Comment: I have edited your answer above to accomodate that how i fixed it, i hope you dont mind. As in my case the issue was for just 2-3 pages , i did it using str_replace function.   But i hope there is some better solution out there if the issue is on too many pages